# Why use process.nextTick() before mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen lots of Mongo (mongoose ORM) Queries being made inside of process.nextTick() method. I know that nextTick defer the execution to next iteration but since [these queries are asynchronous](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) why they use it anyway?

**Example:**

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
      ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: it's not required, or particularly useful.

There are a bunch of Passport tutorials that use this setup: [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local), [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619), [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/).

I have no idea how using `process.nextTick()` came about, but it seems that these tutorials might be borrowing code from either each other, or a common source (that I haven't been able to find).

Because these tutorials rank pretty high on Google, people find them when they are looking for Passport example code, and copy it. So it appears a lot in SO questions as well, perhaps enforcing the idea that it's somehow required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is suitable for heavy load environment in order to not usurp-ate processor for too long (let other instances of `node listen loop` to get their processor time-slice before you make your call to `mongoDB` query).

Comment: Since the MongoDB query is async, it will already yield to the event loop until the query result is returned, so I don't see really the point :-)

Comment: Event loop isn't yield while the function call stack is not empty. In other words, having callback functions in mongoDB async paradigm prevents events from execution till the full rewind from callbacks.